# Video not stream in real device

Tags: android, exoplayer

Recently i'm tried to play .m3u8 video live streaming with Exoplayer. After i'm sometime of coding, and it work fine in Emulator.

Here the problem, when i'm install the APK to the mobile, i found that, url in HTTP are not load but the HTTPS url are work. (Both HTTP and HTTPS are work fine in Emulator). For any resolve this before, please help to advice.

- tried with `android.widget.VideoView`, but look not work as well as `Exoplayer`
- i have include this in manifest

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

`

```
videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoURL));

videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPrepared() {
    videoview.start();
  }
});
```

`

- Expected Http and Https should load if url valid. And it work in Emulator.
- When come to real device, only HTTPS url are work.

Comment: tried with SimpleExoPlayer HLS mode, return the same result, work fine in emulator and not in real mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem cause. It was because of feature and behavior change of Android 9. From now requests without encryption will never work. And by default, the System will expect you to use TLS by default.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28

And because of my emulator was in Android 7 and Real Device are in Android 9, that the reason.